# Disabling Android mediaserver (/system/bin/mediaserver) ASLR

Tags: exploit, android, exploit-development, aslr

I was able to successfully disable ASLR in Kernel on my Android mobile (Cyanogenmod).

```
root@s3ve3g:/system # echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
root@s3ve3g:/system # cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
0
```

However, this does not seem to affect mediaserver (/system/bin/mediaserver).

Found this:

https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.de/2015/09/stagefrightened.html

*"It’s also interesting to note that the mediaserver is a special case, at least on my test phone; it isn’t cloned from a zygote process, but is instead directly execve’ed - this means that the address space is re-randomised on every exploit attempt/run attempt. As a result our brute force is not deterministic, and we can’t put a guaranteed upper-bound on time to exploit."*

And he was able to disable it:

*"Disabling ASLR in the system config"*

How can I disable ASLR for mediaserver process? Which "system config" is this?

Thanks,